# Assign user defined variable to info.plist bool

Tags: ios, xcode, info.plist

Quite often I use a user defined string to assign a value in my info.plist file using the $(VARNAME) syntax in the plist.

I want to do the same for a bool value in the info.plist, but Xcode won't allow me to add the $(VARNAME) syntax to the bool.

Anyone have a way to make this work?

Answer (score 1):

A somewhat hacky and smelly way to achieve this would be to store the `BOOL` as a string. You could either come up with your own string literals for `YES/NO` or you could use the ones that will be interpreted when you call `boolValue` on `NSString` :

> This property is YES on encountering one of "Y", "y", "T", "t", or a digit 1-9—the method ignores any trailing characters. This property is NO if the receiver doesn’t begin with a valid decimal text representation of a number.

Source : https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/nsstring/1409420-boolvalue?language=objc

Answer (score 0):

I manually modified Info.plist to use the variable. I had to use `string` tag for a boolean setting. For example:

```
    <key>LSSupportsOpeningDocumentsInPlace</key>
    <string>$(SHOW_DOCUMENTS_FOLDER)</string>
    <key>UIFileSharingEnabled</key>
    <string>$(SHOW_DOCUMENTS_FOLDER)</string>
```

I used `YES`/`NO` for the variable value.

In the graphical version of Info.plist on XCode the keys show up with value `NO`, but the text version shows the above settings.